# how to read unread sms of one phone from another

Tags: android, sms

I'm developing an application where if my phone is lost, i need to read the unread sms from my phone from other's phone.I tried to update the unread sms in database every half minute.But its updating  only when I open the app.but I need to update it automatically.can anyone please help me for improving this.Or suggest some other way of doing this??. I have posted my code below.

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ListView lViewSMS;

String URL = "http://krith.esy.es/index2.php";

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lViewSMS = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewSMS);
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer t = new Timer(); 
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                              @Override
                              public void run() {
                                  getsms();
                              }

                          },

            0,

            30000);

}
void getsms() {
    String []r;
    r=new String[2];
    fetchInbox();
}

void fetchInbox (){

    final Uri SMS_INBOX = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX, null,"read=0", null, null);
    ArrayList sms = new ArrayList();

    String read=" ";
    String body=" ";
    String[] arr = new String[2];
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {          
        String address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"));
        String person = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("person"));
        String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));
        String protocol =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("protocol"));
        read+= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("read"));
        String status = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("status"));
        String type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type"));
        String subject = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subject"));
        body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"));

        sms.add(address+"\n"+person+"\n"+body+"\n");
        arr[0] = body;
        arr[1] = read;
        if(arr!=null) {
            AttemptLogin attemptLogin = new AttemptLogin();
            attemptLogin.execute(arr[0], arr[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            AttemptLogin attemptLogin = new AttemptLogin();
            attemptLogin.execute("", "");
        }
    }
}
class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String,String,JSONObject> {

    @Override

    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override

    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {



        String msg = args[0];
        String st=args[1];

        ArrayList params = new ArrayList();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("msg", msg));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("st", st));


        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL, "POST", params);


        return json;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {

        try {
            if (result != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to retrieve any data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

}

Comment: Make it becomes a service or Broadcast Receiver when you receive new messages.

Comment: Use BroadCastReceiver to achive this functionality

Comment: i m new to android .can u please tell how to do it..

Answer (score 1):

in Target (lost) device your app should first receive SMS and then Resend it to another Number.
and it needs BroadcastReceiver and SMS Permission [check this tutorial](http://androidexample.com/Incomming_SMS_Broadcast_Receiver_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=62)
http://androidexample.com/Incomming_SMS_Broadcast_Receiver_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=62

Comment: thank you.i will try this.where to include this line                                              Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX, null,"read=0", null, null);

Comment: you don't need that each time new sms arrives should transfer to another number you must not read all SMS DB eveytime

Comment: ya i got it.i should update the db every time with entire message box .and just retrieve the unread sms when needed from db when needed.

Comment: If the target Device is lost then you wont able to get any data from it . So i suggest that you should upload the received sms to your server. with Local database interference as there can be no internet when sms received. Use a Background intent service to upload the sms on server . And retrieve them by using some authenticated Keys on other device